# hardcoding 2D array values

Tags: c++, arrays

Trying to insert values into a 2D array, but the output isnt giving my values, instead random letters

```
int myArr[8][2] = {700,730,760,790,810,840,910,1000}{0.011,0.035,0.105,0.343,0.789,2.17,20,145};
cout  << myArr << endl;
system("Pause");
```

How should I adjust the code, or is it easier to use a text file and insert?

Comment: You can't output a whole array. Try iterating over its elements instead

Comment: If your compiler is not screaming at you for invalid syntax and isn't warning you of possible loss of data for converting double values to ints, you should probably get a different compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numerous problems:

- the array dimensions are wrong
- you don't have outer braces or a comma for the nested arrays
- you're trying to store double precision floating point values in an `int` array
- you can't use `cout` with an entire array.

The array declaration should probably be something like this:

```
double myArr[2][8] = { {700,730,760,790,810,840,910,1000},
                       {0.011,0.035,0.105,0.343,0.789,2.17,20,145} };
```

and to output the contents you could do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    {
        cout << " " << myArr[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/6H0Tci)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

First - you can't print the whole array just by using `cout << myArr`, you need to iterate over the elements of the array using a `for` loop.

Second - you are trying to put decimal values into an integer array which will truncate all of the decimals.

Third - Your array should be sized `myArr[8][2]` not `myArr[2][8]`.  I'm surprised your compiler lets you get away with this.  You should probably look into using a different compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through each row and column, otherwise you're just printing out the pointer value of the array handle.

```
for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
  for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
    cout << myArr[i][j] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}
system("Pause");
```